3次元の立方体同士の衝突検知で、GJKアルゴリズムを使ったが、誤検知される
私は、現在主に、c++とvulkan、glmを使って、3Dのゲームを作成しています。
現在、直方体同士の衝突判定を行うためにGJKアルゴリズムを作製しました。
しかし、下の画像のように立方体同士が離れているのに、衝突していると検知されます。下の画像の場合は衝突していると、コマンドライン上に表示されています。
私は以下の画像のような場合は、衝突していないと検知されるようにしたいです。

なお、上の画像ほど二つの立方体の位置が近いと、衝突していると検知されますが、それぞれの立方体がかなり離れていれば、衝突していないと正しく判定されます。
それぞれの立方体が衝突しておらず、衝突していないと正しく検知される場面

**bool Colider::Intersect(std::shared_ptr<Colider> oppColider)
{
glm::vec3 support = getSupportVector(oppColider, pivot - oppColider->getPivot());
//std::cout << pivot << std::endl;
//std::cout << "opp" << oppColider->getPivot() << std::endl;

Simplex simplex;
simplex.push_front(support);

glm::vec3 dir = -support;

int count = 0;

while (count < 50)
{
    std::cout << coliderVertices[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "OPP" << oppColider->getColiderVertices()[0] << std::endl;

    support = getSupportVector(oppColider, dir);

    //std::cout << glm::dot(support, dir) << std::endl;

    if (glm::dot(support, dir) <= 0.0f)
    {
        return false;
    }

    simplex.push_front(support);

    if (nextSimplex(simplex, dir))
    {
        return true;
    }

    count++;
}

return false;
}

glm::vec3 Colider::getFurthestPoint(glm::vec3 dir)
{
glm::vec3  maxPoint;
float maxDistance = -1000000000.0f;

for (int i = 0; i < getColiderVerticesSize(); i++)
{
    float distance = glm::dot(coliderVertices[i], dir);
    if (distance > maxDistance) {
        maxDistance = distance;
        maxPoint = coliderVertices[i];
    }
}

return maxPoint;
}

glm::vec3 Colider::getSupportVector(std::shared_ptr<Colider> oppColider, glm::vec3 dir)
{
return getFurthestPoint(dir) - oppColider->getFurthestPoint(-dir);
}

bool Colider::Line(Simplex& simplex, glm::vec3 dir)
{
glm::vec3 a = simplex[0];
glm::vec3 b = simplex[1];

glm::vec3 ab = b - a;
glm::vec3 ao = -a;

if (sameDirection(ab, ao)) {
    dir = glm::cross(glm::cross(ab, ao), ab);
}
else
{
    simplex = { a };
    dir = ao;
}

return false;
}

bool Colider::Triangle(Simplex& simplex, glm::vec3 dir)
{
glm::vec3 a = simplex[0];
glm::vec3 b = simplex[1];
glm::vec3 c = simplex[2];

glm::vec3 ab = b - a;
glm::vec3 ac = c - a;
glm::vec3 point = -a;

glm::vec3 triangleCross = glm::cross(ab, ac);

 if (sameDirection(glm::cross(triangleCross, ac), point))
 {
    if (sameDirection(ac, point))
    {
        simplex = { a,c };
        dir = glm::cross(glm::cross(ac, point), ac);
    }
    else
    {
        simplex = { a,b };
        return Line(simplex, dir);
    }
 }
 else
 {
    if (sameDirection(glm::cross(ab, triangleCross), point))
    {
        simplex = { a,b };
        return Line(simplex, dir);
    }
    else
    {
        if (sameDirection(triangleCross, point))
        {
            dir = triangleCross;
        }
        else
        {
            simplex = { a,c,b };
            dir = -triangleCross;
        }
    }
}

return false;
}

bool Colider::Tetrahedron(Simplex& simplex, glm::vec3 dir)
{
glm::vec3 a = simplex[0];
glm::vec3 b = simplex[1];
glm::vec3 c = simplex[2];
glm::vec3 d = simplex[3];

glm::vec3 ab = b - a;
glm::vec3 ac = c - a;
glm::vec3 ad = d - a;
glm::vec3 point = -a;

glm::vec3 abc = glm::cross(ab, ac);
glm::vec3 acd = glm::cross(ac, ad);
glm::vec3 adb = glm::cross(ad, ab);

if (sameDirection(abc, point))
{
    simplex = { a,b,c };
    return Triangle(simplex, dir);
}

if (sameDirection(acd, point))
{
    simplex = { a,c,d };
    return Triangle(simplex, dir);
}

if (sameDirection(adb, point))
{
    simplex = { a,d,b };
    return Triangle(simplex, dir);
}

return true;
}

bool Colider::nextSimplex(Simplex& simplex, glm::vec3 dir)
{
switch (simplex.size) {
case 2: return Line(simplex, dir);
case 3: return Triangle(simplex, dir);
case 4: return Tetrahedron(simplex, dir);
}

return false;
}**

上の部分がGJKアルゴリズムに関数するプログラムです。
GJKアルゴリズムの実装に以下のサイトを参考にしました。
https://winter.dev/articles/gjk-algorithm
こちらのリンクが私のこのプログラムのGitHubへのリンクです。
https://github.com/suikameronn/VulkanGame.git
調べてみたこと
このプログラムの動きを調べたところ、simplexから原点への方向などを調べた後、次のサポートベクトルを求める方向として、ゼロベクトルが求められる部分がありました。
次にTetrahedron関数内の、if文の条件がプログラムを実行した際に、一度もtrueになりませんでした。
もしかしたらここら辺が問題なのかもしれません。
追記
調査してたら、三角形のsimplexを構成した際に、三角形の一つ目(直近で追加した頂点)と二つ目の頂点の座標が同じになっていました。これにより、三角形のsimplex内に原点が含まれているかどうかを調べる際にゼロベクトルが含まれ、四面体を調査する際にもゼロベクトルが含まれてしまっています。もしかしたら、これによりsimplexの次元数が下がってしまっているのかもしれません(三角形のsimplexから線分、四面体のsimplexから三角形へ)

ところどころ引数のdirが値渡しになっていますね。
参考サイトでは左辺値参照で渡されているので、それが原因かもしれません。
追記
dirが更新されずに次のsupportを取得したために、同じ座標がsimplexに追加されているっぽいですね。
